# Select first letter of name with linq query from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I want to select first letter of name and change font-weight like following code;

```
var selectList = db.Users.Select(x =>  x.Name.Substring(0,1)).FirstOrDefault();

telList.Items.Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < alpha.Length; i++) {
    ListItem listItem = new ListItem(Convert.ToString(alpha[i]));
    listItem.Attributes.Add("value", Convert.ToString(i));

    if (selectList == s) {
        listItem.Attributes.Add("class", "class2");
    } else {
        listItem.Attributes.Add("class", "class1");
    }
    telList.Items.Add(listItem);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you already have code. What exactly was your question?

Comment: @cubrr  I didnt get selectlist value correctly. I am sory for late

Comment: @GrantWinney didnt work if condition.I am sory for late

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution

```
     List<string> Capitals = (from u in db.Users
                                 select u.Name[0].ToString().ToUpper()).Distinct().ToList();


        telList.Items.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < alpha.Length; i++)
        {




            ListItem listItem = new ListItem(Convert.ToString(alpha[i]));
            listItem.Attributes.Add("value", Convert.ToString(i));

            for (int j = 0; j < Capitals.Count; j++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(alpha[i]) == Capitals[j])
                {
                    listItem.Attributes.Add("class", "class1");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    listItem.Attributes.Add("class", "class2");
                }
            }



            telList.Items.Add(listItem);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = db.Users.Select(x =>  x.Name.Substring(0,1)).FirstOrDefault();

telList.Items.Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < alpha.Length; i++) {
    var listItem = new ListItem(Convert.ToString(alpha[i]));
    listItem.Attributes.Add("value", Convert.ToString(i));

    if (Convert.ToString(i) == s) {
        listItem.Attributes.Add("class", "class2");
    } else {
        listItem.Attributes.Add("class", "class1");
    }
    telList.Items.Add(listItem);
}
```

Alternatively:

```
var s = db.Users.Select(x =>  x.Name.Substring(0,1)).FirstOrDefault();
telList.Items.Clear();
telList.Attributes.Add("data-firstletter",s);
telList.Items.AddRange(alpha.Select((letter,index)=>new ListItem(letter,index.ToString()));
```

then use css to style your listitem (assuming your select has the id telList):

```
#telList > li { font-weight: normal; }
#telList[data-firstletter=A] > li[value=0],
#telList[data-firstletter=B] > li[value=1],
#telList[data-firstletter=C] > li[value=2],
#telList[data-firstletter=D] > li[value=3],
#telList[data-firstletter=E] > li[value=4],
#telList[data-firstletter=F] > li[value=5],
...
#telList[data-firstletter=Z] > li[value=25] {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I try first part of the your code but didnt work. I dont understand alternatively part